# Как выделить каждое слово в тексте поочередно по нажатию комбинации клавиш?

Tags: c#, winforms, строки, richtextbox

У меня есть текст в RichTextBox, Хочу по нажатию на комбинацию клавиш поочередно выделить все слова текста (символы от пробела до пробела, знака препинания, или конца текста). Для этого добавил `KeyEventHandler`и написал такой код в его обработчике:

```
 private void hotKeys(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

  if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) {
     if (richTextBox.Focused)
     {
     richTextBox.SelectionLength = richTextBox.Text.Length - richTextBox.SelectionStart;
     string text = richTextBox.SelectedText;
     int endOfWord = Regex.Match(text, @"\s+").Index;
     richTextBox.SelectionLength = endOfWord;
                    
     } 
  }
}
```

Он правильно выделяет символы от пробела до пробела в тексте, но есть одна проблема: перед следующим вызовом метода надо снимать выделение со слова вручную. Покажу на скрине. Допустим, я вызываю метод первый раз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сразу же нажать комбинацию клавиш второй раз, то выделится то же слово "Слово1", но если вручную, допустим стрелкой, передвинуть каретку к началу следующего слова и вызвать `hotKeys` то метод выделит его:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы можно было вызывать метод подряд. Или как передвинуть каретку после выделения текста, но при этом выделение оставить? У меня была мысль добавить в код, что-то типа:

```
if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) {
                if (richTextBox.Focused)
                {
                    richTextBox.SelectionLength = richTextBox.Text.Length - richTextBox.SelectionStart;
                    string text = richTextBox.SelectedText;
                    int endOfWord = Regex.Match(text, @"\s+").Index;
                    richTextBox.SelectionLength = endOfWord;
                    // После выделения передвигаем каретку
                    richTextBox.SelectionStart = endOfWord;
                    richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                } 
            }
        }
```

Но тогда каретка "прыгает" то в конец то в начало первого слова при каждом вызове метода, а выделения нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правка:

У `RichTextBox` по умолчанию есть перемещение каретки с `ctrl`. Вот оно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скрине каретка передвинулась к началу "слово2". Я хочу реализовать такое поведение:
Нажали на ctrl+Right первый раз:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем второй:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Выделил текст мышкой для демонстрации)

Comment: Не использйте `Alt`, его может отлавливать главное меню приложения. попробуйте с `Ctrl`. И событие `KeyDown` надо повесить на сам RTB, а не на форму, тогда не потребуется проверять `Focused`. Чтобы снять выделение, надо задать `.SelectionLength = 0`.

Comment: @aepot В том то и дело, что снимать выделение мне не надо. Мне надо как то передвинуть каретку, но выделение оставить на предыдущем слове,

Comment: т.е. вам нужно выделить первое слово, потом выделить второе, но с промежутком где пробел ? а такое вообще в этом контроле возможно ?) мне кажется нет

Comment: @PavelPopov Без промежутка где пробел. Просто если я в конце метода задам .SelectionLength =0 как предложил aepot то у меня просто снимется выделение    со слова, вот что я имел ввиду.

Comment: При поведении по умолчанию, выделение снимается, если перемещать каретку через Control, что с этим не так? Хочется просто сохранить выделение? Кстати, я по-всякому попрыгал по тексту и с зажатыми `Ctrl+Shift`, и просто с `Ctrl`, все работает "из коробки" как ожидается. Что именно вас не устроило, что вы начали вот этим вот всем заниматься?

Comment: @aepot я знаю, что оно работает из коробки)) Есть комбинация клавиш Ctrl + Right которая из коробки бегает до конца слова, но без выделения  и Shift+ctrl+Right которая выделяет по слову но не снимает выделение с предыдущих. а я хочу реализовать комбинацию, чтобы снимала выделение с предыдущего,

Comment: Еще раз. 1) Вы хотите, чтобы при `Ctrl+Right` каретка передвигалась не снимая виделения 2) При `Ctrl+Shift+Right` выделялось только одно послелнее слово. Так? Тогда вопрос: а как мне теперь выделить 2 слова? Только мышкой?

Comment: @aepot Еще раз : 1) Чтобы каретка передвинулась к началу следующего слова (как по умолчанию), но при этом еще было выделено предыдущее слово.. 2) Ctrl+Shift+Right трогать вообще не надо это был пример, чтоб показать гибрид каких операций по умолчанию я хочу.

Comment: Смотрите, каретка технически при выделенном фрагменте не может быть нигде кроме как в начале выделения и в конце. При **любом** передвижении каретки выделение снимается. То есть, вы не сможете оторвать каретку от выделения не меняя само выделение. Если такое сделать очень надо, потребуется нетривиальная реализация своей версии `RichTextBox`. Как я теперь понял, относительно дефолтного поведения, вам просто нужно выделить предыдущее слово при перемещении каретки через `Ctrl`?

Comment: @aepot Да, Вы правильно поняли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привяжите эти два обработчика к `RichTextBox` событиям `KeyDown` и `KeyUp` соответственно.

```cs
private int selectionStart = 0;

private void RichTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Shift && e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left))
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            int pos = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = pos - selectionStart;
        }
        else
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = selectionStart - richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    }
}

private void RichTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Shift && e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left))
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart += richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
        selectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

Либо в дизайнере - выбрать `RichTextBox`, нажать кнопочку с молнией, выбрать нужное событие из перечисленных выше, и выбрать обработчик из выпадающего списка, либо через вставку вот такого кода в `Form.Load`.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.KeyDown += RichTextBox1_KeyDown;
    richTextBox1.KeyUp += RichTextBox1_KeyUp;
}
```

А свой обработчик `hotKeys` при этом отключите, иначе может не сработать.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял задачу то этот код должен работать

```
int start = 0;
int lengthminus = 0;
//Событие получения фокуса
private void OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   richTextBox.SelectionStart=0;
   start=0;
   lengthminus = 0;
}
private void hotKeys(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

  if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) {
     if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
     {
        if (richTextBox1.Focused)
        {
           string target = " ,.:;";//символы которые будут концом выделения
           char[] anyOf = target.ToCharArray();
           if (start + 1 < richTextBox1.Text.Length)
           {
              int length = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOfAny(anyOf, start + 1);//длина для выделения
              int length1 = length;
              length -= lengthminus;
              if (lengthminus < richTextBox1.Text.Length)
              {
                 lengthminus = length1;
                 if (length < 0)
                 {
                    length = richTextBox1.Text.Length - start;
                 }
                 richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
                 richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;
                 start += length;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем это все с фокусами? Если можно обработчики на RTB повесить? И у вас опечатка в названии переменной. :)

Comment: Мне с RTB не доводилось работать.

Comment: Да это без разницы, он тот же текстбокс, только с дополнительными фишками. Про обработку событий нажатия кнопок - оно одинаково со всеми контролами работает.

Comment: Ну тогда по идее должен работать

Comment: @antonkovalskyi Не работает. При вызове все время выделяет первое слово

Comment: А сейчас перепроверьте

Comment: Я добавил start+=length;

Comment: @antonkovalskyi теперь length остается от предыдущего слова. То есть если первое слово было 4 буквы, а второе 10 — выделятся только 4 буквы второго слова,

Comment: Я создал проект и проверил у меня работает.

Comment: @antonkovalskyi Могу Вам скрин показать.

Comment: Показывайте, очень странно что не работает

Comment: @antonkovalskyi Вот https://ibb.co/2qPWpf0

Comment: Я нашел ошибку, сейчас скину

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Я изменил работу, но я думаю что лучше заменить alt, на другую кнопку.